# Calendar loses functionalities and design features

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar that functions perfectly with a site administror.

[image]

Unfortunately, with another user, the layout is different (arrows are missing for example) and cannot add new events.
I've even given this user full control on the site but with no luck.

What could it be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I logged in the browser with CTRL-SHIFT and run with another user. So, to change user I now use /_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
the page is rendered perfectly, amd the problem is solved