# Pages render differently according to user

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-server, css

pages render differently according to the user.

I have even given to a second user full control and ownership of the site.
Still pages are wrongly rendered .

I notice for example that calendar misses graphic elements and possibility to add new events.
The favicon though points to the right icon doesn't show up in the url bar. It does with a site administrator.

Comment: Is this related to this (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103623/calendar-loses-functionalities-and-design-features) post? Are all your css checked in, and have you done any masterpage modifications for example?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot to check how it is different?

Comment: Yes Robert Lindgren, it is related but it's broader as I came to realize that the problem is not only related to a calendar. Aanchal in the post Robert pointed out there is a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If a page renders differently for a site administrator than for an unprivileged user, you likely have files that have been modified or checked in, but **not published**.

For display issues, it's probably your CSS file.  Find any CSS files linked to the page and republish.  Default file location is in `/_styles/`.

If whole page elements are not displaying, you likely haven't published the page itself.  When viewed as the site admin, you'll get one of two messages:

[image: Checked out and editable.]

[image: Checked in and viewable by authorized users.]

Either way, you need to publish the page.  It's unlikely you have a rights/permissions issue, since you have already given the second user full control.

Another thing: if it only happens on one computer, it could be a browser caching issue.  Try force refreshing the page (in Internet Explorer, do Ctrl + F5).  This will force the browser to ignore cached images and elements when reloading.  Alternately, you could clear the browser's cache and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a permissions issue, since it works for site admins. Easiest way to confirm is adding this user to the site admins and verifying they can see everything. It usually means some one has broken inheritance of permissions.

Check this for some starting tips on troubleshotting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=py5y49zTpN4

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I logged in the browser with CTRL-SHIFT and run with another user. So, to change user I now use /_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
the page is rendered perfectly, amd the problem is solved

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer. I hope it's more clear now