# Site renders differently for other user

Tags: 2010, publishing, design

One of my projects at work this summer has been to redesign a SharePoint 2010 website which will launch within the next few months. Everything looks great on my end, but for another user, the website displays incorrectly as if SharePoint is selectively applying CSS rules.

#### This is how it is supposed to display:

[image: screenshot]

#### This is how it is displaying for her:

[image: screenshot]

In both cases, the same stylesheets and scripts are loaded in the same order. I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I gave her full control, and the problem still remains. I also tried publishing and approving all pages, stylesheets, scripts, etc. like [Pages render differently according to user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103629/pages-render-differently-according-to-user) recommended, but that did not fix the problem either.

The problem persists across all pages on different page layouts (publishing is enabled across the site collection). It also persists on different computers.

Are there any settings that may cause this, or is the problem different?

Comment: Maybe she has an old cached version on the stylesheet? (Shift-f5 or Ctrl-f5)

Comment: It does the same thing on my browser when I am logged in as her, and on different computers. Logging back in as myself on any computer fixes it.

Comment: Definitely permissions then... maybe page layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- check if all branding resources (css, js, images, master page, page layouts, pages) are checked in, published and approved
- make sure you are testing side by side using the same specs (e.g. browser version)
- confirm if in both cases the setting `display intranet sites in compatibility mode` is the same, as one of them might be rendering on a lower IE mode
- If everything else is good, try opening the site from within one of the frontend servers. load balancers cache your branding resources, so in some cases this cache needs to be cleared

Comment: Re-published and re-approved two files and the problem was fixed.